# How to make a grid background pattern for NSView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

is there an easy way to get this grid background? Or do I have to do it something like this `[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage ...]]`?

[image: Screenshot of interface]

I don't want complete code. I just want to know if there is an easy way to do that and if yes how.

Comment: not for mac but for iOS, but it maybe will you get started: [Practical Drawing for iOS Developers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=129)

Comment: @methanol, did any of the answers give you what you wanted to know? If so then please accept that answer to allow assigning the points for it.

Comment: @MikeLischke if you meant with "points", reputation then yes - I have done it already. I upvoted both of the answers. None of them were exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
[[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, dirtyRect);

for (int i = 1; i < [self bounds].size.height / 10; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:100/255.0 green:149/255.0 blue:237/255.0 alpha:0.3] set];
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:100/255.0 green:149/255.0 blue:237/255.0 alpha:0.2] set];
    } else {
        [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:100/255.0 green:149/255.0 blue:237/255.0 alpha:0.1] set];
    }
    [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(0, i * 10 - 0.5) toPoint:NSMakePoint([self bounds].size.width, i * 10 - 0.5)];
}
for (int i = 1; i < [self bounds].size.width / 10; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:100/255.0 green:149/255.0 blue:237/255.0 alpha:0.3] set];
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:100/255.0 green:149/255.0 blue:237/255.0 alpha:0.2] set];
    } else {
        [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:100/255.0 green:149/255.0 blue:237/255.0 alpha:0.1] set];
    }
    [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(i * 10 - 0.5, 0) toPoint:NSMakePoint(i * 10 - 0.5, [self bounds].size.height)];
}

}
```

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 4):

The same but for **Swift 4**

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    if let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext {
        NSColor.white.setFill()
        context.fill(dirtyRect)
        context.flush()
    }

    for i in 1...(Int(self.bounds.size.height) / 10) {
        if i % 10 == 0 {
            NSColor.init(red: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.3).set()
        }else if i % 5 == 0 {
            NSColor.init(red: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.2).set()
        }else{
            NSColor.init(red: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.1).set()
        }            
        NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5), to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5))
    }

    for i in 1...(Int(self.bounds.size.width) / 10) {
        if i % 10 == 0 {
            NSColor.init(red: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.3).set()
        }else if i % 5 == 0 {
            NSColor.init(red: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.2).set()
        }else{
            NSColor.init(red: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.1).set()
        }
        NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5, y:0), to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5, y: self.bounds.size.height))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a pattern color is a good solution here, especially since you need to vary the lines. Instead use an NSBezierPath and moveToPoint/lineToPoint pairs for each horizontal and vertical line. You can then draw the grid in one call. Do extra steps for those lines with a different color (alpha) and/or width (i.e. don't add the thicker lines to the main grid path but create a separate one for them).

Comment: It's The varying line widths aren't a problem, really. You just have to make the pattern one of the large (thick) boxes in size, instead of one of the small boxes. Since the boxes can then just be repeatedly blitted, this may even be less CPU-intensive than having Quartz actually calculate and anti-alias all of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at [the Sketch example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html) that comes with every Xcode installation or is available as a separate download, too.

It features a grid implementation (and many other useful demonstrations of Cocoa techniques..) allowing for zooming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Porting Methanol's solution for swift and resolving error in MacOS 10.10 onwards.

A simple static function could be used and called from drawRect()

```
static func makeGridBackground(dirtyRect: NSRect, view: NSView){
    //view.print("WMEditorUtils: initiated drawing")

    //Fill background with white color
    if let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext {
        NSColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, dirtyRect)
        CGContextFlush(context)
    }

    //Draw Lines: Horizontal
    for var i:Int = 1; i < (Int)(view.bounds.size.height / 10); i++ {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            NSColor(deviceRed: 100.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3).set()
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            NSColor(deviceRed: 100.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2).set()
        }
        else{
            NSColor(deviceRed: 100.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 0.1).set()
        }
        NSBezierPath.strokeLineFromPoint(NSMakePoint(0, (CGFloat)(i * 10) - 0.5), toPoint: NSMakePoint(view.bounds.size.width, (CGFloat)(i * 10) - 0.5))
    }

    //Draw Lines: Vertical
    for var i:Int = 1; i < (Int)(view.bounds.size.width / 10); i++ {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            NSColor(deviceRed: 100.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3).set()
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            NSColor(deviceRed: 100.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2).set()
        }
        else{
            NSColor(deviceRed: 100.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 0.1).set()
        }
        NSBezierPath.strokeLineFromPoint(NSMakePoint((CGFloat)(i * 10) - 0.5, 0), toPoint: NSMakePoint((CGFloat)(i * 10) - 0.5, view.bounds.size.width))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same of "sad tuna" but in **Swift 3**

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    if let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext {
        NSColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, dirtyRect)
        CGContextFlush(context)
    }

    for i in 1...(Int(self.bounds.size.height) / 10) {
        if i % 10 == 0 {
            NSColor(SRGBRed: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.3).set()
        }else if i % 5 == 0 {
            NSColor(SRGBRed: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.2).set()
        }else{
            NSColor(SRGBRed: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.1).set()
        }

        NSBezierPath.strokeLineFromPoint(CGPointMake(0, CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5), toPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5))
    }

    for i in 1...(Int(self.bounds.size.width) / 10) {
        if i % 10 == 0 {
            NSColor(SRGBRed: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.3).set()
        }else if i % 5 == 0 {
            NSColor(SRGBRed: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.2).set()
        }else{
            NSColor(SRGBRed: 100/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 0.1).set()
        }

        NSBezierPath.strokeLineFromPoint(CGPointMake(CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5, 0), toPoint: CGPointMake(CGFloat(i) * 10 - 0.5, self.bounds.size.height))
    }
}
```